# Rotation of video to be sent to Web Service

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

What I'm trying to do sounds simple enough but I can't figure out for the life of me how to do it. When sending a video to my webservice it is always rotated 90 degrees. I want to be able to rotate it so it isn't sideways. I have all the code working perfectly up until this point.

I had the same issue with pictures also, but I was able to make a category that checked the orientation of UIImage object and adjust it accordingly.

The following is the code I'm using to save the movie. At some point before I send the video off, I want to have it rotated.

```
        else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {            
        NSLog(@"Movie");
        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
        NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]path];
        if(UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath)){
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
            [[WebCall sharedClient] postRequestWithVideo:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                connectionLabel.text = operation.responseString;
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                connectionLabel.text = operation.responseString;
            } atPath:videoData]; 
        }            
    }
```

Please Help.